# How to check if a different program is using the camera/microphone in python ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu

I'm trying to check in python (ubuntu) if a different program is using the camera/microphone of my computer.
I thought of which syscalls are being used when accessing the camera/microphone.
I know that the syscalls "access" and "open" are being used but there are probably specific parameters for that.
And if I know which syscalls are being used, how can I also know if the
program is using those specific syscalls?

I have an example code in which I'm checking if a file.exe added any new files:

```
if "open(\"" + file_path + "\", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_CLOEXEC, 0666) = 3" in system_calls_list:
            programs_which_added_new_files.append(file_path)
```

First, I have created a file which adds new files and than I wrote all the syscalls of the file to a list (system_calls_list). And than I'm checking if it has a specific syscall (open) with specific parameters. If it dos'e, I can know that the file I'm checking added new files and than append it's path to a different list (programs_which_added_new_files). The same concept should go to camera/microphone.

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Hi, Please share your code and let users know what you have tried so far

Comment: Hope it is more clear now

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there exists multiple audio frameworks for Linux.

The oldest, OSS, uses multiple device names under `/dev` that you are supposed to open (see [list here](http://manuals.opensound.com/developer/oss_devices.html)). It is unlikely that you have this installed on a recent Ubuntu.

What you are probably using is ALSA and PulseAudio. In this case, the program is probably connecting to PulseAudio over a UNIX socket (for example `/run/user/1000/pulse/native`), but this is an implementation detail of PulseAudio (in particular it can also work over IP). You should use the PulseAudio API to find out, for example if you run `pactl list source-outputs` you should see a list of clients and the recording devices they are connected to.